# How to upgrade mongoDb 1.4.4 to 1.6.5 in ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I want to upgrade mongoDb 1.4.4 to 1.6.5 because mongoid not support 1.4.4
go through http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Upgrading+to+1.8 this but unable to understand please give me a easy tutorial for upgrading same

Answer (score 0):

It's should be straightforward to upgrade using the [10gen Ubuntu installation instructions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian-or-ubuntu-linux/).

The latest MongoDB production version is currently 2.0 series (2.0.6 as of today); this is also the [minimum version required for Mongoid 3](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html#installation).

The [release notes](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/2.0+Release+Notes#2.0ReleaseNotes-Upgrading) include information on upgrading, but in general the releases are drop-in replacements with no change required to your data files.

As with any upgrade, you should first back up your existing data using [mongodump](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools#ImportExportTools-mongodumpandmongorestore) in case there are any unexpected issues.